# Kernel / determinant of this continuous operator

Tags: functional-analysis, linear-transformations, determinant

Consider the operator $\phi_1$ which takes a continuous function $u$ defined over $[0,1]$ and returns the function $\phi_1(u)$ defined over $\mathbb{R}$ constructed such that it is odd and $2$-antiperiodic. Simarly, consider $\phi_2$ such that $\phi_2(u)$ is odd and $2$-periodic.

Lastly, for any $t_1>0$ and $t_2>0$, define the operator $\Delta$ which maps two continuous functions $u,v$ defined over $[0,1]$ to a function of $\mathbb{R}$:

\begin{align}
\Delta(u,v):x\mapsto \,&\phi_1(u)(x+ct_1)  + \phi_1(u)(x-ct_1) - \phi_2(u)(x+ct_2)  - \phi_2(u)(x-ct_2) 
\\ &\quad + \dfrac{1}{c}\int_{x-ct_1}^{x+ct_1} \phi_1(v)(s)\,\mathrm{d}s - \dfrac{1}{c}\int_{x-ct_2}^{x+ct_2} \phi_2(v)(s)\,\mathrm{d}s
\end{align}
where $c>0$ is a scalar (you will probably have recognized the difference of two d'Alembert solutions).

I would like to characterize $t_1,t_2,u,v$ such that $\Delta(u,v)$ has a non trivial kernel. I must say I have never faced such a problem in the continous framework and have no idea how to start or even if it is possible to solve it.